# shrink middle div horizontally on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column layout which I'm creating using inline-block divs. The left and right columns are fixed widths but the inner column is to hold dynamic content and should expand horizontally as required by it's content width.

That's easy enough... the tricky part is that when the browser window is smaller (horizontally) than the width of the left, right and expanded middle divs, I would like the middle div to scroll and the side columns to stay fixed. In other words, the middle div's size should shrink and grow with window resize but should not grow beyond the available space.

Simply laying out the divs looks like this
https://jsfiddle.net/xzjp5xef/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="lcol">
      left
   </div>
   <div id="midcol">
      <div id="spacer">
         150px spacer
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="rightcol">
      right
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#container{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#lcol {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100px;    
}
#midcol {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#spacer {
    min-width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}
#rightcol {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
}
```

The point of the "spacer" div is to represent the dynamic content which in this case I've fixed to 150px plus padding. So in this case I want the divs to lay out the way they do in the above fiddle, but then when the window is shrunk horizontally, I want the *middle* div to scroll and the left and right divs to remain fully visible.

That fails because then the window gets a scroll bar but the middle panel remains the same width and the right hand div disappears into the scrolled region.

My next attempt was using absolute positioning
https://jsfiddle.net/n4zrLqh2/
I fixed the left div to the left and the right div to the right and set the middle div's right and left properties. This is a neat trick which allows the middle div to stretch and take up all available space. This works nicely but doesn't create the effect I'm after when the window is big - because I don't want the middle column to expand further than is necessary to contain its content.

In the end I've solved this with javascript but would much prefer a CSS solution.

Edit: To help others see what I'm trying to achieve, here's the complete javascript solution (which I'd prefer to achieve with pure CSS):

HTML:

```
<div id="lcol">left</div>
<div id="midcol">
    <div id="spacer">150px spacer</div>
</div>
<div id="rightcol">right</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height:200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
}
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:0px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
#lcol {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 100px;
}
#midcol {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#spacer {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 5px;
}
#rightcol {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (with jquery)

```
function adjustSizes() {
    // Sizes of middle divs are dynamic. Adjust once
    // built or whenever the viewport resizes
    //
    var $leftDiv = $('#lcol')
    var $milddleDiv = $('#midcol');
    var $rightDiv = $('#rightcol');

    // 1. Resize middle div to available viewport space
    var maxBodyWidth = $(window).innerWidth() - ($leftDiv.outerWidth() + $rightDiv.outerWidth());
    $milddleDiv.css('maxWidth', maxBodyWidth);

}

$(window).resize(function () {
    adjustSizes();
});
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjmekkgj/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think setting `max-width` of `spacer` will solve your problem in case content increases. 
Set `max-width` to `calc(100vw - 200px)` if all margin and padding are 0. Otherwise adjust the value 200px taking margin, padding into account.
I have created a plunker. Please check if it solves your issue. Try checking after running plunker in spearate window
http://plnkr.co/edit/WG9v0MyiD2hiaZrOA3Yw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I've used this solution in my implementation because it required the least modification. +1 for showing me "calc".... didn't know about that!

Comment: This is nice and simple. Just note that calc() is not compatible with a few older browsers. If you don't care about handling IE8 or anything before the latest Android browser, you're set.

(See: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 1):

For the one example you provided, since the left and right columns are positioned absolutely, you should take up the space somehow. I used padding on the middle column, then nested a "content" block inside that represents the visible part of the middle column. Then, I put `overflow-x: auto;` on the new content block and set a `max-width` on the overall container to force the new block to shrink.

(In previous edits, I was attempting to do this same thing but with floats instead of absolutely positioned divs)

```css
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

#container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}

.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background: blue;
}

#mid {
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 100px;
}
#mid > .content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#spacer {
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="column">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="mid" class="column">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="spacer">
                150px spacer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="column">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

...and [in JSFiddle form](https://jsfiddle.net/n4zrLqh2/3/)

Comment: The "spacer" I'm using needs to essentially determine the maximum width of the middle div - I don't want it to expand beyond that. In your fiddle example, the middle div expands to all available space. It is therefore similar to my fiddle using absolute positioning.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Updated the code. Let me know if that was what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks, that's closer in terms of the initial layout but with that one, when you shrink the window the middle div's contents hides behind the others - I want it to scroll horizontally. I've added my javascript solution to my original question (and fiddle link) to show the outcome I'm after... but with CSS only, no javascript!

Comment: @JamesThorpe Okay, one more update made. Hope that helps!

Comment: It does, thanks! Clever trick - adding a container div in the middle with the left and right padding to the other columns' widths. For my implementation I've gone with manpreet singh's "calc" option above because it means I don't have to add a container div and is therefore slightly simpler to modify my existing code. +1 for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` can do that.

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
#lcol {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
#midcol {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#rightcol {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="lcol">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="midcol">
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xzjp5xef/4/) (showing overflow effect).

Support is IE10 and up.

Comment: Thanks, but my second fiddle above also manages the same solution  using absolute positioning to make the middle box take up all available space. Unfortunately I want the middle box to not take up more space than is required to accommodate the contents horizontally... even if more is available. In other words, the right col should not always right-align with the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the middle div to have a max width with a percentage so it will get thinner with the screen size:

```
.midcol { 
  max-width: 25%; 
}
```

I put a value for the max-width in there for an example, but you can change the value.

Comment: That would make the middle div size and shrink proportionally, yes, but that's not what I'm after - I want the middle div to size to the width of its contents if that width is available, otherwise to size to max available width and then horizontally scroll to accommodate overflow.